# Javascript in Static Resources for security review but requires parameter

Tags: javascript, static-resources, security-review

I have a package that was submitted for security review which requires JS to be in static resources.

*Required: all script and style resources must be loaded through static resources 
Do not load resources dynamically with a link or script tag.
Do not hotlink to JavaScript code outside of static resources.*

From https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/appinnovators/AppExchange_Security_Requirements_Checklist

However there is a page which uses google maps api and so there is a reference to their javascript

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=renderMap&key=keygoeshere" >
    </script>
```

As part of this the api key is passed in the url, how can this be done with the JS in a static resource.
And is there not an issue with putting it in a static resource anyway in case google updates the JS.